# CSV imported file to table gets repeated on Rails server restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I've got a scaffold generated, which renders the table:

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Plant id</th>
      <th>Species</th>
      <th>Vector</th>
      <th>Link</th>
      <th>Genotyping summary</th>
      <th>Short note</th>
      <th>Live</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tests.each do |test| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= test.Plant_ID %></td>
        <td><%= test.Species %></td>
        <td><%= test.Vector %></td>
        <td><%= test.Link %></td>
        <td><%= test.Genotyping_summary %></td>
        <td><%= test.Short_note %></td>
        <td><%= test.Live %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', test %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_test_path(test) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', test, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and I have imported my CSV file

```rb
require 'csv'    
csv_text = File.read('app/assets/csv/plant_table.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  Test.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

CSV File text:

```
Plant_ID,Species,Vector,Link,Genotyping_summary,Short_note,Live
PLANT1,C. sinsensis “Valencia”,YCVXXX1,www.google.com,./files/PLANT1.png,,TRUE
PLANT2,C. sinsensis “Valencia”,YCVXXX1,www.google.com,./files/PLANT2.png,,TRUE
```

My problem is everytime I close my rails server and restart it with `rails s` the table repeats itself. I want it to:

- Delete everything and create it again from CSV file
  or
- Check if the item already exists and, if so, skip it. Avoid duplicates somehow

Is this possible?
I've tried `:unique => true` as I've read this in another post, but from what I've read that was database oriented.

First `rails s`
[image]

Cancel and `rails s` again:
[image]

Comment: You can do `Test.delete_all` before importing the file . Where did you put that `unique: true`? I'm not sure why you need to import the file every time during startup but consider checking the `seeds` file and the `db:reset` command if you need to truncate/seed the database often.

Comment: Great, this was the correct answer as well, but I'll try checking the seeds for that seems like a cleaner solution. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand much about seeds, but when I restart the rails server, the ID of each page is increased by the number of IDs there were before... e.g.: if my Plant: YCCXXX1 has an id = 1 and I restart the server, it will be id = 14. If I restart again, it will be id = 27 and so on. Do you know why? - Its not a big thing but it's an inconvenience

Comment: If you want your database to start from 1 again you need to tell it so, that depends on each database engine I think, google `yourdatabase reset autoincrement id counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
require 'csv'    
csv_text = File.read('app/assets/csv/plant_table.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
Test.destroy_all # << Add this line
csv.each do |row|
  Test.create!(row.to_hash)
end
```

The added line will remove all your Test records for your database before they are re-added.

Comment: When I restart the rails server, the ID of each page is increased by the number of IDs there were before... e.g.: if my 
 Plant: YCCXXX1 has an id = 1 and I restart the server, it will be id = 14. If I restart again, it will be id = 27 and so on. Why is this?

Comment: The ID is generated in the database.  Each time a record is created it creates a new id. This makes sure all ids are unique but it does mean that they are not reused if records are deleted.